# Access to data from OrderedDict in Python and loop over it

Tags: python, django, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have an `OrderedDict` in my Django application which let to get `content edition` and `content subversions` for each edition.

It looks like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()

for version in list_of_edition():
    od.setdefault((version.pk, version.title), []).extend([(subversion.pk, subversion.title) for subversion in version.collection.all()])
```

I get:

```
OrderedDict([((2, '10th Edition (Current)'), [(58464, 'Ph. Eur. 10.0 lite')]), ((1, '9th Edition'), [(21928, 'Ph. Eur. 9.8 lite'), (29235, 'Ph. Eur. 9.9 lite'), (36542, 'Ph. Eur. 9.10 lite')])])

# Rewritten in order to get more readable
OrderedDict(
    [
        (
            (2, '10th Edition (Current)', True), [(58464, 'Ph. Eur. 10.0 lite')]
        ),
        (
            (1, '9th Edition', True), [(21928, 'Ph. Eur. 9.8 lite'), (29235, 'Ph. Eur. 9.9 lite'), (36542, 'Ph. Eur. 9.10 lite')]
        )
    ]
)
```

This OrderedDict lets me to create tabs for navigation in navbar menu.
It should be:

```
Tab : 10th Edition (Current) 
    |
    ---> subtab : Ph. Eur. 10.0 lite

Tab : 9th Edition
    |
    ---> subtab : Ph. Eur. 9.8 lite
    |
    ---> subtab : Ph. Eur. 9.9 lite
    |
    ---> subtab : Ph. Eur. 9.10 lite
```

In my **menu.py** file, menu is created like this:

```
content_children = (
    AdminMenuItem(_('Manage smth1'), reverse('smth1-list'), weight=100, separator=False),
    AdminMenuItem(_('Manage smth2'), reverse('smth2-list'), weight=100, separator=False),
    ...
)

Menu.add_item('content', MenuItem(_('Content'), '#content', children=content_children)
```

So I'm trying to loop over OrderedDict in order to create my menu like the example before. I'm getting some difficulties to isolate each menu and add submenus for each menu associated:

```
edition_children = ()
for version in od:
    for element in od[version]:
        edition_children += MenuItem(element[1], reverse('home'), weight=150, separator=False),

for version in od:
    Menu.add_item('edition', MenuItem(version[1], '#', children=edition_children))
```

It gives me:

[image]

It's the same thing for `9th Edition`. For `10th Edition`, I should have only `Ph. Eur. 10.x` and for `9th Edition`, I should have only `Ph. Eur. 9.x`

Thank you very much by advance

Comment: Are you asking how to separate `edition_children` items for different `od`s?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't overcome to handle my OrderedDict up to now :/

Comment: No idea why you're talking about `OrderedDict` so much. Add a key to edition_children or decrease edition_children's scope as Daniel suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a list of all sub-versions and then add that list to all editions.

Re-arrange your loop like this:

```
for version in od:
    edition_children = ()
    for element in od[version]:
        edition_children += MenuItem(element[1], reverse('home'), weight=150, separator=False),
    Menu.add_item('edition', MenuItem(version[1], '#', children=edition_children))
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much ! I spent lot of time on this part (create the OrderedDict, handle it ...) ! It works now :)